Viśvakarman helping Indra kill his son
Tvaṣt is also known as Viśvakarman. His sons Trishira and Vritra were killed by Indra using Vajra weapon.
From Dadhichi's bone, Viśvakarman made those Vajra and other divine weapons.
Why did Viśvakarman help Indra in making those weapons when he himself created those sons to defeat Indra?
